# Virtual Box Unsupported version 17 of data unit 'cpum'

Tags: virtualbox

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.

Unsupported version 17 of data unit 'cpum' (`instance #1`, `pass 0xffffffff`) (`VERR_SSM_UNSUPPORTED_DATA_UNIT_VERSION`).

> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>
> Component: Console
>
> Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}

I got this error code when I tried to open my virtual box this morning, which works perfectly fine yesterday. I saved my machine state before turning off the computer. I uninstalled `Bluestacks` this morning, and install(then unistall) `Droid4X`, which I think to be the source of problem, since `Droid4X` somehow was listed on my `VirtualBox`. Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Answer (score 24):

For me, this problem occurred while updating virtual box to the higher version and my virtual machine are in a saved state instance. So I have to Discard the  Saved state. Then stared it as normal. It's works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[SOLVED]
To fix it, edit your vbox file (ex: MyWin7.vbox)
And just remove the section "stateFile" in global configuration.

Before:

Machine uuid="{051685d4-f6b6-4994-a3cb-cc30271e280b}" name="MyWin7" OSType="WindowsXP_64" stateFile="Snapshots/2016-10-26T08-14-10-696037500Z.sav" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2016-11-07T11:07:35Z"

After:

Machine uuid="{051685d4-f6b6-4994-a3cb-cc30271e280b}" name="MyWin7" OSType="WindowsXP_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2016-11-07T11:07:35Z"

restart your VM

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this issue with an error message: 
"Unsupported version 4 of data unit 'pci'"
with a Ubuntu 14 VM on VirtualBox 5.1 for Mac. I originally used VB 5.2 when I setup the VM, saved it, then had to downgrade VBox (to use Vagrant), which I suppose caused this issue. The fix was similar, which is hard-rebooting the VM to skip the saved state. I did it from the UI though - right click, select Start/Normal Start. There would be a warning about discarding the saved sate but this wasn't a problem for me.